# Switch DB From local SQL to AZURE DB with MVC5 App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I've Create MVC5 APP with Local DB like the following link(step 1 to 5) 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application
And the application is running as expected and now I need to change the DB from the 
sql Lite **to azure DB** ,I have created the same DB in azure (same data structure)and now what I want that the application use this DB ,There is simple way to do that ?

Im using VS2013 for web.

Comment: Have you followed the tutorial for this? If you want to deploy your website on azure as well, there's a step-by-step documentation for this

Comment: @serv-can you provide this docu please,Im stuck :(?

Comment: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/ there you go

Comment: @Serv- Thanks I already see that...the adding class but I didnt see where you actually connect it to the azure DB. in addtion there is no way to do that by add ADO.net entity frame work and generate from the DB that I already created in azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the "source" and "initial catalog" parameters of the connection string in the web.config file.
Also, SQL Azure doesn't work with integrated security so you need to remove the "integrated security" parameter from the connection string and add the parameters "User ID" and "Password" with the credential of a user that you created in SQL Azure.

- Open Visual Studio In Solution Explorer
- find the file web.config
- Look for the section connectionStrings

You should find something similar to:

```
<add name="testEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\test.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

You need to:

- Replace (LocalDB)\v11.0 with the name of your server
- Remove "attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\test.mdf;integrated security=True;"
- Add "Initial catalog=[name of your database in SQL Azure];user id=[name of your user id on SQL Azure];password=[your password]

Comment: Thanks Andrea, voted up,Im very new to this topic e.g. where the source is locketed etc ,can you please provide step by step example

Comment: I put some step-by-step example in my previous reply